# STL - assignment operator vs. `assign` member function

Tags: c++, stl, operators, assignment-operator, assign

`vector` (as well as `list` and other containers) has a member function (MF) `assign`.
I want to compare the `assign` MF (range version) vs. the assignment operator.

As far as I understand it is useful to use `assign` when:

1. One wants to assign a sub-range of the vector (not from the beginning to the end).
2. The assignment is done from an array.

In other cases there are no cons to the `assign` MF and the assignment operator could be used.
Am I right?
Are there some other reasons for using `assign` MF?

Comment: Another *pro* for assignment is move-assignment operator. If you assign an rvalue, it'll be moved from instead of copied from.

Comment: A small con of `assign` is that it is slightly less intuitive to someone else reading your code than just an equals sign, but that's a small matter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main reason for using `assign` is to copy data from one type of container to another.

For example, if you want to migrate the contents of an `std::set<int>` to an `std::vector<int>`, you can't use the assignment operator, but you can use `vector.assign(set.begin(), set.end())`.

Another example would be copying the contents of two containers holding different types that are convertible to one or the other; If you try to assign `std::vector<Derived*>` to an `std::vector<Base*>`, the assignment operator is insufficient.

Comment: You can still do `vector = std::vector<int>(set.begin(), set.end())` etc., so `assign` is completely redundant.

Comment: @emlai `assign` is useful if you want to re-use capacity instead of allocating a completely new vector.